# Order by before using in For XML Path with GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```sql
CREATE TABLE #AD 
(
    [PART NUMBER] nvarchar(255), 
    [PLANT] nvarchar(255), 
    [VENDOR CODE] nvarchar(255), 
    [SUPPLIER NAME] nvarchar(255), 
    [POSTING DATE] int
)

INSERT INTO #AD 
VALUES ('123', '1001', '1', 'VEND1', 20220304),
       ('123', '1001', '2', 'VEND2', 20220611)

SELECT 
    AD.*,
    REPLACE(STUFF((SELECT (', (' + AD2.[VENDOR CODE] + ') ' + AD2.[SUPPLIER NAME])
                   FROM #AD AD2
                   WHERE AD.[PART NUMBER] = AD2.[PART NUMBER] 
                     AND AD.PLANT = AD2.PLANT 
                     AND (AD2.[POSTING DATE] BETWEEN 20220101 AND 20221231)-- Is there a way to order this by POSTING DATE DESC within here?
                   GROUP BY AD2.[VENDOR CODE], AD2.[SUPPLIER NAME] 
                   FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, ''), '&amp;', '&') AS [Supplier]
FROM  
    #AD AD
```

**Desired Output:**

| PART NUMBER | PLANT | VENDOR CODE | SUPPLIER NAME | POSTING DATE | Supplier |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1001 | 1 | VEND1 | 20220304 | (2) VEND2, (1) VEND1 |
| 123 | 1001 | 2 | VEND2 | 20220611 | (2) VEND2, (1) VEND1 |

I want to order the suppliers column to have the most recent supplier first (most recent posting date, so should list Vend2 first in this case). I tried just adding an `ORDER BY [POSTING DATE] DESC` right before `FOR XML PATH`, but I can't do that because I don't want to add it to the select statement or group by.

I also tried doing a subquery of just selecting everything ordering by posting date but you cannot order by within a subquery.

Any thoughts on accomplishing this?

Comment: What is your SQL Server version (`SELECT @@VERSION`)?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP3-GDR) (KB5014355) - 13.0.6419.1 (X64)   May 29 2022 21:05:29   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Please add a desired output to the question.

Comment: maybe STRING_AGG is the better concept which has an order By

Comment: The `STRING_AGG()` is available starting from SQL Server 2017 onwards. The OP is on SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still order the dates, only you need an aggregation function.

I used `ORDER BY MAX(AD2.[POSTING DATE]) DESC` that should bring the right order

Still as I posted in my comment, an update to something more recent, brings some benefits including `STRING_AGG`

```
CREATE TABLE #AD 
(
    [PART NUMBER] nvarchar(255), 
    [PLANT] nvarchar(255), 
    [VENDOR CODE] nvarchar(255), 
    [SUPPLIER NAME] nvarchar(255), 
    [POSTING DATE] int
)

INSERT INTO #AD 
VALUES ('123', '1001', '1', 'VEND1', 20220304),
       ('123', '1001', '2', 'VEND2', 20220611)

SELECT 
    AD.*,
    REPLACE(STUFF((SELECT (', (' + AD2.[VENDOR CODE] + ') ' + AD2.[SUPPLIER NAME])
                   FROM #AD AD2
                   WHERE AD.[PART NUMBER] = AD2.[PART NUMBER] 
                     AND AD.PLANT = AD2.PLANT 
                     AND (AD2.[POSTING DATE] BETWEEN 20220101 AND 20221231)-- Is there a way to order this by POSTING DATE DESC within here?
                   GROUP BY AD2.[VENDOR CODE], AD2.[SUPPLIER NAME] 
  ORDER BY MAX(AD2.[POSTING DATE]) DESC
                   FOR XML PATH('') ), 1, 2, '')
  , '&', '&') AS [Supplier]
FROM  
    #AD AD
```

| PART NUMBER | PLANT | VENDOR CODE | SUPPLIER NAME | POSTING DATE | Supplier |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1001 | 1 | VEND1 | 20220304 | (2) VEND2, (1) VEND1 |
| 123 | 1001 | 2 | VEND2 | 20220611 | (2) VEND2, (1) VEND1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nSU6oE5d)

Answer (score 0):

How about the following solution?

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE 
(
    [PART NUMBER] nvarchar(255), 
    [PLANT] nvarchar(255), 
    [VENDOR CODE] nvarchar(255), 
    [SUPPLIER NAME] nvarchar(255), 
    [POSTING DATE] int
);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES 
('123', '1001', '1', 'VEND1', 20220304),
('123', '1001', '2', 'VEND2', 20220611);

SELECT * FROM @tbl;

SELECT AD.[PART NUMBER], ad.PLANT
    , REPLACE(STUFF((SELECT (', (' + AD2.[VENDOR CODE] + ') ' + AD2.[SUPPLIER NAME])
                   FROM @tbl AD2
                   WHERE AD.[PART NUMBER] = AD2.[PART NUMBER] 
                     AND AD.PLANT = AD2.PLANT 
                     AND (AD2.[POSTING DATE] BETWEEN 20220101 AND 20221231)-- Is there a way to order this by POSTING DATE DESC within here?
                   ORDER BY AD2.[POSTING DATE] DESC
                   FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, ''), '&amp;', '&') AS [Supplier]
FROM @tbl AD
GROUP BY AD.[PART NUMBER], ad.PLANT;
```

**Output**

| PART NUMBER | PLANT | Supplier |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1001 | (2) VEND2, (1) VEND1 |

Comment: I am also trying to avoid grouping in the outer query as there are a lot of other fields and joins that this snippet is embedded in with a different grouping in the outer query. Makes this somewhat difficult. I thought of an over clause to use a window function but that doesn't work with for xml path.